# What caused the conflict between the Kree and the Xandarians?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

What caused the original 'thousand year war' between the Kree and the Xandarians?

Comment: I'm not sure this currently has an official answer. All references I can find just state that it's been going on for a thousand years, but there are no hints as to the cause of it.

Comment: When you've been at war for thousands of years, does anyone really remember what started it?

Comment: It was probably a Three's Company-esque misunderstanding.

Comment: @BrianDHall - Or what their Sharon said about our Jenny's dress at Cousin Doreen's wedding. Unforgiveable.

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is, we have no idea.

### Marvel Cinematic Universe

The *Guardians of The Galaxy*  movie never goes into any detail about the origins of the war. At the start of the movie, the war has "been going on" for a long time. Indeed, the Nova Corps on Xandar was formed largely to defend Xandar from the Kree. (This is why their crafts are so well equipped to counter Ronan's vessel near the end.)

### Mainstream Marvel

As far as I know, there was never anything like a Kree/Xandarian war in the mainstream Marvel continuity. The closest I could find was an instance where the Nova Corps became involved in a war between the Kree and the Shi'ar.

In the comics, the main enemy of the Kree race are the Skrull, with the [Kree-Skrull](http://marvel.wikia.com/Kree-Skrull_War) War taking up quite a lot of space in the Avengers comics.

There *is* some history between the Guardians of the Galaxy and the Kree; the origin story from Earth-616 has the Guardians forming to fight off the Kree invasion of a star system, just not the one Xandar is in.

(I can *speculate* that Nova Corps just made a convenient "clearly-the-good-guys" space faring group to put into the Guardian's origin story, that was slightly less bizarre than Cosmo the talking dog. So they invented the war to give Ronan an excuse to be mad at Xandar and kick-start the story.)

Comment: It's a minor point, but where does it say that the Nova Corps ships were designed specifically to counter that kind of Kree vessel?  It seemed to me more like a generally useful ability, which happened to fit this battle particularly well.  Otherwise, +1.

Comment: that part was actually my assumption based on the fact that they were so readily prepared for it, plus the fact that the Kree were their primary enemy, but you may be right.

Answer (score 12):

I'm unaware of any specific reason mentioned in the film to describe why the Kree and the Nova Empire went to war for. That being said, the Kree are described on the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Kree) as extremely aggressive and expansionist, having existed in a state of near-constant warfare with their neighbours (including the largely peaceful Skrulls) for **hundreds** of millennia.

> The Kree launched an attack upon the Skrull empire and the peaceful
> Skrulls were again forced to become war-like to defend themselves. The
> Kree-Skrull War would continue for hundreds of thousands of years.

**The best guess would be that the Nova Empire are merely the latest in a long line of victims of their enmity.**